# query string for inserting elements in npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core-mvc, query-string, npgsql

I want to insert data into a row in PostgreSQL from NPGSQL, but there is something wrong with my query string. Can you please suggest modify it?

```
   public IActionResult Create(string item_name, string item_count, string item_size)
    {
        using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
        connection.Open();
        string query = @"INSERT INTO public.""items""(""item_count"",""item_name"",""item_size"")VALUES ('"+item_count+item_count+item_count+"')";
        using var command = new NpgsqlCommand(query, connection);
        int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();



        if (result < 0)
        {
            return Error();
        }
        return View(nameof(Create));

    }
```

Comment: Keep in mind concatenating strings, or using string.Format could open you up to a sql injection attack.  Using parameters helps mitigate that risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way.
You have forgotten to add "," between the values and also add quotes if the value is string or date.

```
public IActionResult Create(string item_name, string item_count, string item_size)
{
    using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
    connection.Open();
    string query =  String.Format(@"INSERT INTO public.""items""(""item_count"",""item_name"",""item_size"")VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}');" , item_count , item_count ,item_count);
    using var command = new NpgsqlCommand(query, connection);
    int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (result < 0)
    {
        return Error();
    }
    return View(nameof(Create));
}
```

Comment: If you feel this will help you, please upvote the answer.